# how to limit number of characters with complete word in regular expression

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a requirement to Print Long String into different strings with character limit as 20 with complete word and spaces, symbols, commas, dots has to be allowed.

Lets say the String is:

> I have String Search the whole web or only webpages After doing some
>   research I think that I want to combine an if/then statement with
>   lookahead, i.e. go to the character limit and if there is a character
>   following it that is a space, add an ellipses, if it is a number or
>   letter, go to the final space within the limit and add an ellipses

It has to print like:

> I have String Search  ------> 20Characters with Complete Word
>   the
>   whole web or          ------> 16C because limit is 20 but next word
>   Complete's at 21C So its limit to 16C 
>   only webpages After   ------->
>   19C because limit is 20 but next word ends at 25C

Comment: Is what environment? Using what tools? What programming language? Does it have to be using regexp?

Comment: You could make things a lot easier by including this crucial information from the start. What have you tried? where is your code? *(again)* Does the solution have to use regexp?

Comment: i submitted my code what i have tried...

Comment: `(.){0,20}\s` will give you as many words as it can fit in 20 chars but it would probably be more effciient just to find the last space  in 20 char truncation.

Comment: my output in console is                                          match: Indian vers
match: ion of this popular s
match:  web or only webpages
match:  Indian vers
match: ion of this popular s
match:  web or only webpages
match:  After doing some res
match:  combine an if/then s
match: limit and if there is

Comment: Please Help me out...

Comment: Hmm this assumes a language with whitespace and punctuation word boundaries. Pretty naive requirement if working with data sets you cannot know in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use this RegEx Pattern: `(.{1,20})(?:\s|$)`

Escaped RegEx: `(.{1,20})(?:\\s|$)`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/pU4kI8

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in objective-c i have added slash for s tag its worked great for me..`(.{1,20})(?:\\s|$)`

Comment: You're welcome. Yes slashes need escaping in objective-c. Updated my post with the escaped Regex. Accept the answer if it solved your problem.